# Installing IBM Traveler 9 on 64-bit CentOS 6.8

Tags: linux, centos, ibm

I'm trying to install IBM Traveler 9.0.1.12 on a 64-bit version of CentOS 6.8 via command line. Domino 9.0.1 installed without any problems.

When I run the silent installer, I get the following error:

```
[root@traveler]# ./TravelerSetup -f installer.properties -i silent -l en
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "abort", detail "" at 2016/08/03 11:54:27 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/tmp/install.dir.1813/core.20160803.115427.1813.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /tmp/install.dir.1813/core.20160803.115427.1813.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/install.dir.1813/javacore.20160803.115427.1813.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /tmp/install.dir.1813/javacore.20160803.115427.1813.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/tmp/install.dir.1813/Snap.20160803.115427.1813.0003.trc' in response to an event
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
Aborted
```

According to [the documentation at IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21681128), in order to install in silent mode, I need these libraries:

- glibc-2.12-1.7.el6.i686
- libgcc-4.4.4-13.el6.i686
- libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.i686

I did make sure all of these libraries were installed using yum, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean Cull's comment on [this blog post](http://dominothoughts.com/domthoughts/domthoughts.nsf/dx/installing-domino-on-linux-resolving-missing-requirements.htm) pointed me in the right direction:

Edit the yum configuration file

```
vi /etc/yum.conf
```

Add the following line

```
multilib_policy=all
```

After that you can install the 32bit library

```
yum -y install libstdc++
```

Running the silent installer now returns the following result:

```
[root@traveler bitos.adm]# ./TravelerSetup -f installer.properties -i silent -l en

IBM Traveler 9.0.1.12 build 201607061004
Silent install started..
IBM Traveler version 9.0.1.12 build 201607061004 will be installed.
Installing for Domino version 9.0.1.
Program Directory:
  /opt/ibm/domino/notes/latest/linux
Data Directory:
  /opt/ibm/domino/data/
Set user home page as default:
No
Linux user name:  notes
Linux group name:  notes
Installing files..

Installation completed successfully.
```